# ubuntu linux - remap mouse scroll wheel to arbitrary keyboard keys

Tags: mouse

Is it possible to have the scroll wheel on my mouse send a keystroke instead? so when i scroll upward it sends the letter "a" and downward it sends the letter "b"?

Comment: There's no need to crosspost. The site moderators can handle moving questions around.

Comment: i don't know how to delete my question off stack overflow!

Comment: You don't. You flag it for moderator attention, and they'll handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Try **imwheel**, **xmodmap** and/or **xinput**.